# Overriding an async method not adding async to method signature

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, overriding

I wonder why when I use visual studio to override RemoveLoginAsync()

it looks like this:

```
public override Task<IdentityResult> RemoveLoginAsync(string userId, UserLoginInfo login)
```

And not like:

```
public override async Task<IdentityResult> RemoveLoginAsync(string userId, UserLoginInfo login)
```

Shouldn't it be an awaitable Task using `async`?

Comment: Is that being filled in by ReSharper or Visual Studio?

Comment: The `async` modifier is not part of the method signature. It's just na instruction for the compiler to create a state machine.

Comment: @PauloMorgado: True, but the default should be to provide `async`, IMO. Eliding `async` is the rare (and more dangerous) case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't it be an awaitable Task using async?

A `Task` is an awaitable. It implements the `GetAwaiter` pattern. Marking a method with `async` is simply a flag to the compiler which tells it to transform this method call to a state-machine. But, not all `Task` returning methods need to be marked as `async`. For example:

```
public Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oh yay!");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In this example, I "faked" an asynchronous operation by returning [`Task.CompletedTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask(v=vs.110).aspx), I didn't actually need to `await` anything.

Another, more realistic example:

```
public Task SendWebRequestAsync()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    return httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
}
```

When I'm returning a `Task` rather than awaiting it, I'm deferring the awaiting on the task to the method higher up the callstack. This means that I don't allocate a state-machine and I'm also changing a bit the way the exception handling will work here. But, since this is a "tail async call", I don't have to `await` the operation and hence there's no need for the `async` modifier.

Comment: So, specifically RemoveLoginAsync removes a db record, this should be awaitable, should I add async in that case?

Comment: If you're going to `await` on an asynchronous method inside `RemoveLoginAsync` then yes. Otherwise, you won't be able to.